# Динамическое присвоение параметров кнопкам в android

Tags: android, eclipse

Есть такой код, создающий 5 кнопок:

```
package com.example.test23;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    Button button1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        int i = 0;
        while (i<=5) {
            myCreateButton(i);
            i++;
        }

    }

    private void myCreateButton(int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LinearLayout layout1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);
        button1 = new Button(this);
        button1.setText("test " + String.valueOf(i));
        button1.setTag(String.valueOf(i));
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        layout1.addView(button1);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("TEST_CLICK", (String) button1.getTag());
    }

}
```

Так вот, хочу что бы при нажатии выводилась конкретная цифра, присвоенная кнопке. А то сейчас выводится только последняя присвоенная цифра на всех кнопках.

Answer (score 3):

замени

```
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("TEST_CLICK", (String) button1.getTag());
}
```

на

```
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("TEST_CLICK", (String) arg0.getTag());
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Всё работает как надо))